# Doing File I/O in Python with non-ASCII Characters

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-io, localization

I'm working on a Python script that reads an XML file encoded with UTF-8, does some manipulation with it and saves it to Google's Datastore (it's an App Engine program).

The way I'm reading and parsing the files is just with file.readline() and a few regular expressions. The only problem is that the file I'm working with has characters from a lot of different languages in it, so for example, it might have an é or Å or Russian or Greek characters.

I was getting an error like this at first: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)." I then tried switching the encoding on the file open to "ISO-8859-15" which gets rid of the error but the outputted characters aren't displayed right.

So my question is: how to work with a file encoded in UTF-8 in Python without Python getting stuck on all of the special characters in the file? I hope this was clear enough, and thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are your patterns and strings to be searched unicode strings?

Comment: Yes - as in I'm not searching for any special characters with my regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the UTF-8 encoding on `str.decode`

```
>>> print '\xe2\x99\x9e'.decode('utf-8')
♞
```

That's supposed to be a chess piece but it's too tiny to see :)

Comment: @Nick Whatever can you mean ;)?

Comment: @Blender Me? Did I say something?

Comment: when I use the decode function it works sometimes but I also get a Unicode Decode Error. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: That means your input doesn't conform to the encoding you specified, UTF-8 in this case. Are you sure it's UTF-8? What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

You say you changed the encoding you use with the file to ISO-8859-1. Did you try changing it to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer and with reference to [effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-objects.htm) you could handle each line like this:

```
raw = file.readline()
proc = raw.decode('utf-8')
```